# What's the point of using L2TP together with IPSec?

Tags: networking, ip, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

According to my limited understanding, IPSec authenticates peers and encapsulates/encrypts IP packets in tunnel mode.

On another hand, L2TP itself does not offer authentication/encryption, but offers encapsulation, which is already achieved by IPSec.

In my application, I would like to secure end-to-end data transfer using IPSec. I am also considering "L2TP/IPSec" but cannot figure out which L2TP feature is not offered by IPSec? Why would I choose to use L2TP/IPSec rather than IPSec alone?

Answer (score 1):

The reason people use L2TP/IPsec, rather than plain IPsec in tunnel mode, is to have a user-level authentication layer in addition to the host-level authentication provided by IPsec.

Ref: http://seclists.org/basics/2005/Apr/139